Gratis Android email client with good spam filtering
Looking for a gratis app.
For a few years I used K9, but had problems, probably because I have multiple email addresses each with years worth of email.
Then I turned to BlueMail, and that was fine for years, but recently it has been letting through shed loads of spam.
I have my own domain, and fetch mail form there, after it has ben filtered by Spam Assassin.  I get a little spam in Thunderbird on my desktop, but far too much in BlueMail on Android.
Please recommend something that you personally use. Thanks.
I strongly prefer if it doesn't send my credentials and emails through someone else's server, just collects from my own server (using IMAP)
